# Are messages published in an Akka Distributed Publish Subscribe cluster using a full or partial mesh?

Tags: akka, publish-subscribe, akka-cluster, gossip

I'm interested in using Akka's Distributed Publish Subscribe Cluster feature to publish messages sent over a cluster. When using DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish, are messages broadcasted to all topic subscribers using a full mesh network topology, or is gossip used to optimize the propagation of published messages using a partial network mesh? Thanking you in advance

Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/distributed-pub-sub.html